# Why would the example test in Laravel fail for redirect?

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit, eloquent

Please explain why Laravel 4's example test fails for me.

My "/" route redirects to "login" in my routes.php file.

(Oh, I've RTFMed and scoured several sites, blogs, and tuts.)

```
-sh-3.2$ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.0.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/dev/phpunit.xml

The Xdebug extension is not loaded. No code coverage will be generated.

F

Time: 83 ms, Memory: 13.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/dev/app/tests/ExampleTest.php:14

FAILURES!                            
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
-sh-3.2$
```

Here is the code from ExampleTest.php

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: Without the test code, it's hard to tell

Comment: NOTE: Changing title to fails on redirect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test is failing because you're getting 302 status code instead of 200 (since there is a redirection that wasn't in the default routes.php file).

If you want to test redirection, then Laravel provides several methods just for that.

1. If you're using named routes:

   `$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('login');`
2. If not:

   `$this->assertRedirectedTo('login');`
3. For testing response status codes:

   `$this->assertResponseStatus(302);`

Comment: thanks. that's a good start to understanding this rabbit trail. will watch for more answers before i mark a best answer.

Comment: I'll doubt you'll get any more answers as this is the correct one.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the redirect is occurring though (at least not in a way I can understand it). I expect something to do with routes.php file as described but it's not clear exactly what is meant there. I.e. what does it mean? – "since there is a redirection that wasn't in the default routes.php". How can he know that there is a redirection? Where would one see this redirection in the code? How could one disabled it?

Comment: btw I didn't intentionally down-vote this answer and now it won't let me change my vote :(

Comment: @geoidesic I could have worded it better. OP had modified the `routes.php` and the default route (`/`) was redirecting somewhere else instead of displaying a view. The test was not updated to reflect the changes, hence the failure.

Comment: Oh, and don't worry about the down-vote. They're just Internet points and don't really matter. :)

Comment: So you're saying that 302 is the correct response because there is a route? Doesn't seem great to me that every route you create will cause a 302 response. That means one's entire Laravel app will return 302 on every page, because nothing works without routes in Laravel. Unless I'm misunderstanding something. Ok wait – re-read that. So any route that doesn't display a view will be 302.